# solving for a variable that exist inside as well as outside of natural log or exponent

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

can the following equation be solved for K analytically? If not, then what other approaches I could try out?

```
K*ln[(C2-K)/(C1-K)] = -(F/V)*t
```

The original equation was:

```
C2 = K + (C1-K)*exp(-(F/KV)*t)
```

Comment: Do not expect this to have a nice solution. Look into root-finding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) instead.

Comment: You would have to use the Lambert W function to find it in closed terms.

Comment: You can call $-F/V*t$ another variable so that it doesn't look as messy.

Answer (score 1):

To start, I point out a few things.

A) You could simply solve for $K$ using [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

B) You could try to solve for $K$ in closed form using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

As for A), you will need to understand calculus.

As for B), I know it won't work, it only works to solve *some* problems of this type.

I can solve the following:

$$K\ln(K)=A$$

$$K^K=e^A$$

$$K=e^{W(A)}$$

Solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Square_super-root).
However, a problem like:

$$K\ln(K+a)=A$$

Is unsolvable.

Yours is also unsolvable.