# How to solve equation for a variable that is inside and outside an exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I have this equation

$$y=x\exp\big(a(1−xk)\big).$$

It is possible to solve for $x$?
I can see from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625783/solving-for-a-variable-that-exist-inside-as-well-as-outside-of-natural-log-or-ex) that sometimes there is no solution. Is this also the case? Is there a numerical approach that can be used?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\Catalan{\mathsf{Catalan}}$

The solution in terms of the Lambert $\W$ function is found as follows:

\begin{align} 
x\exp(a(1-xk))&=y
,\\
x\exp(a-akx)&=y
,\\
x\exp(a)\exp(-akx)&=y
,\\
x\exp(-akx)&=y\exp(-a)
,\\
-akx\exp(-akx)&=-aky\exp(-a)
,\\
\W\left(-akx\exp(-akx)\right)&=W(-aky\exp(-a))
,\\
-akx&=W(-aky\exp(-a))
,\\
x&=-\frac1{ak}\,W(-aky\exp(-a))
.
\end{align}

The number of real solutions is defined by the value of the argument
$-aky\exp(-a)$ of $\W$.

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 1):

The [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $W(z)$ satisfies $We^W=z$. Since $-akye^{-a}=-akx\exp(-akx)$, each solution comes from one [branch of $W$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Elementary_properties,_branches_and_range) viz. $x=-\tfrac{1}{ak}W(-akye^{-a})$.